# Select the last record in MySQL in WHERE condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that store ticket and statue relation

```
ticketstatus_Id ticket_Id status_Id
===================================
1                1          1
2                1          2
3                1          3
4                2          1
5                2          2   *
6                3          1
7                4          1
8                3          2   *
```

I want to select rows that last status_Id equal 2 ,Rows are marked in table.
 I think I have to use GROUP BY on column ticket_Id but it return with first status_Id.

Comment: Do you want to target the "last" status ID (as determined by some column), or does last here mean greatest status ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a good candidate for `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_Id ORDER BY ticketstatus_Id DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ticketstatus_Id, ticket_Id, status_Id
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1 AND status_Id = 2;
```

The above logic finds all latest rows for each `ticket_Id`, as ordered by the `ticketstatus_Id`, whose `status_Id` values also happens to be 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `group by` and a `having` clause:

```
select ticket_Id, max(ticketstatus_Id)
from ticketstatuses
group by ticket_id
having max(ticketstatus_Id) = max(case when status_id = 2 then ticketstatus_Id end);
```

It would be interesting to know if this has better performance than the `row_number()` version.  However, for performance, this is probably best:

```
select ts.*
from ticketstatuses ts
where ts.ticketstatus_Id = (select max(ts2.ticketstatus_Id)
                            from ticketstatus ts2
                            where ts2.ticket_id = ts.ticket_id
                           ) and
      ts.status_id = 2;
```

This can take advantage of an index on `(ticket_id, ticketstatus_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

All records with `status_Id= '2'`

```
Select * from TABLENAME where status_Id = '2'
```

Last record with `status_Id= '2'`

```
Select * from TABLENAME where status_Id = '2' order by  ticketstatus_Id  desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * from `TABLENAME` where `status_Id` = '2' ORDER BY  `ticketstatus_Id` DESC LIMIT 1;